# Marketing Cloud SQL To Convert Epoch (string) to Date Time?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am trying to convert from Epoch Date to Regular date. I tried the below SQL but it didn't work.

```
SELECT 

epdate, 
convert(varchar, convert(date, epdate, 105), 101) AS epdate 

FROM tablea
```

Any idea how to convert it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this question:

[How to correctly convert Unix Timestamp to datetime in SQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/360624/how-to-correctly-convert-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql/360662#360662)

A plain convert is not enough - you need to add the number from your string to epoch start date ('1970/1/1').